# CONCAT() statement doesn't INSERT INTO table

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, phpmyadmin, sqldatatypes

This code runs perfectly fine on its own but not part of an INSERT INTO statement? I get the error: `#1292 - Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ''` when running it as part of an INSERT statement in phpMyAdmin? I am concatinating a string and integer in the CONCAT() function. The field I'm trying to insert into is a VARCHAR(255).

```
 (SELECT CAST(CONCAT((SELECT wp_wpdatatable_2.prefix FROM wp_wpdatatable_2, wp_wpdatatable_9 WHERE wp_wpdatatable_9.client = wp_wpdatatable_2.wdt_ID AND wp_wpdatatable_9.wdt_ID = 811 LIMIT 1),         
     CASE WHEN (SELECT wp_wpdatatable_5.entryid FROM wp_wpdatatable_9, wp_wpdatatable_5 WHERE wp_wpdatatable_9.entryid = wp_wpdatatable_5.entryid LIMIT 1) 
      THEN (SELECT MAX(CAST( TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(wp_wpdatatable_5.reference,'[0-9]+')) AS INT)) FROM wp_wpdatatable_5, wp_wpdatatable_9 WHERE wp_wpdatatable_5.client = wp_wpdatatable_9.client AND wp_wpdatatable_9.wdt_ID = 811 AND wp_wpdatatable_9.entryid = wp_wpdatatable_5.entryid ORDER BY wp_wpdatatable_5.reference DESC LIMIT 1)
      
      ELSE (SELECT MAX(CAST( TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(wp_wpdatatable_5.reference,'[0-9]+')) AS INT)) + 1 FROM wp_wpdatatable_5, wp_wpdatatable_9 WHERE wp_wpdatatable_5.client = wp_wpdatatable_9.client AND wp_wpdatatable_9.wdt_ID = 811 ORDER BY wp_wpdatatable_5.reference DESC LIMIT 1) END) AS CHAR))
```

Comment: If the number is `0` and you trim all the leading zeroes, you end up with an empty string.

Comment: There's no need to remove leading 0 before casting to `INT`. They'll be ignored.

Comment: You can't use `CAST(... AS INT)`. To cast to integer you have to use `AS SIGNED`. See the list of allowed types [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for your help. I've changed the INT to SIGNED but it still doesn't work :( I find it strange that the portion of code works perfectly fine on its own (as a standard SELECT) but not when putting it as part of an INSERT INTO?

Comment: It's an error when you're trying to insert into a table, it's only a warning when you're selecting. Do the standard SELECT and then do `SHOW WARNINGS` to see it.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar but when I place ````SHOW WARNINGS;```` at the end of the query it just outputs that exact text (SHOW WARNINGS) to the console?

Comment: You do this as a separate query after the first query. I don't know what the equivalent is in PhpMyAdmin, I use the command line mysql application.

Comment: Yes I did it as a separate query after the first one. I just tried ```SHOW COUNT(*) WARNINGS``` and am getting a result o zero (which is expected from the SELECT statement)? If I place the warnings code at the end of the INSERT, it never gets to it as the insert breaks the whole thing :(

Comment: I don't know why you're not seeing it. I just tried `select cast('' as signed);` then `SHOW WARNINGS` showed the same `Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ''`  message

Comment: `CAST( TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM  REGEXP_SUBSTR(...)) AS INT)` --> `0 + REGEXP_SUBSTR(...)

Comment: `CAST(CONCAT(...) AS CHAR)` --> `CONCAT(...)` -- Concat delivers a string; no need to CAST.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table you are INSERTing into.  Also provide the `INSERT` part of the statement.  I suspect the columns are not lined up.  Or there is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `id` that you did not account for.